# Convert positive number e.g. +7 to twos complement in 8 bits showing a leading 1 using 4 step method

Tags: binary, twos-complement

For the purposes of teaching, I wish to understand the following in the context of the method (four steps, see below): I am trying to convert +7 to twos complement in 8 bits. The answer, as per shown on https://www.allmath.com/twos-complement.php is as below:

Decimal 7
Binary  0000 0111
Complement  **1111 1001**

This shows a negative number as it starts with 1.

Shouldn't the answer be 0111.

I want to be able to derive the answer using these four steps.

STEP 1: Convert magnitude (7) to binary.  0111
STEP 2: Pad 0's to desired bit size.  0000 0111
STEP 3: Invert bits to achieve 1's-complement.  1 1 1 1  1 0 0 0
STEP 4: Add 1 to achieve 2's-complement.

ADD                1
------------------>
**1 1 1 1  1 0 0 1**

Where am I going wrong in understanding this. When working with twos complement numbers we were taught that if it started with a 1 it was negative. So what is a method for converting positive decimal numbers into twos complement, or do we assume that for any positive decimal number the twos complement is just itself:

e.g 7 = 0111 or  0000 0111 if in 8 bits?

This would also suggest then that the 4 step method above CANNOT be used for POSITIVE numbers?

Comment: That website is for negating the number (using "two's complement negation"), not for converting it to "two's complement representation" (ie the system in which negation is implemented by the two's complement operation). The terminology is confusing.

Comment: @harold could you read the last part of my question (updated) and confirm either way. So do we assume +7 or any positive decimal number in twos complement format is just itself?

Comment: Yes, positive numbers in "two's complement" are just themselves, in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Discussion

*(note that discussion here uses **TCR** for "Two's Complement Representation")*

Unfortunately, the material you provided here (allmath.com) probably misunderstood what is "Two's Complement". There are many books have provide the canonical definitions for it, for the sake of convenience, it suffices to quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

The very first sentence:

> Two's complement is a mathematical operation on binary numbers

, along with the definition for its [mathematical operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_from_two%27s_complement_representation):

> w = -a_{n-1}2^{n-1} + a_{n-2}2^{n-2} + ... + a_{0}2^{0}

Take a binary number `11111001` as an example. Without TCR, we can interprate it as `2^7 + 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 1 = 249`. With TCR (i.e. applying the mathematical operation), we view it as `-2^7 + 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 1 = -7`.

Similiary, for another binary number, say `00000111`. Without TCR, we view it as `2^2 + 2^1 + 1 = 7`. And with TCR, we view it as `2^2 + 2^1 + 1 = 7`, which is identical to the former one.

#### Back to your scenario

Your 4-step operations are essentially: **obtaining the TCR for the negation of a given number**.

Again, taking `11111001` as an example, after your 4-step operations, it turns into  `00000111`, which is `7`, i.e. the negation of `-7 (11111001)`. Similiary, after your 4-step operations, `00000111` turns into `11111001`, which is `-7`, i.e. the negation of `7 (00000111)`. Thus, the result of your 4-step operations is call **Two's Complement Negation**, instead of **Two's Complement**.

#### Why is easy to be confusing?

One reason might be: *Nearly all computers adopt the TCR notion*. Assuming a 8-bit computer, when we want to see how would our computer display the decimal number `7`, our computer would directly print out `7`, which is very intuitive for most people. However, for decimal number `249`, it usually does not "obey your commands", instead, it prints out the another value: `-7`.

Conversely, if you want your computer to display `-7`, accoding to [Cornell University's Lecture Notes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Etomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html), the things you need to do are:

1. Start from the absolute value of `-7`, which is `7`;
2. Take `7`'s binary representation (i.e. `00000111`) as input.
3. Invert the bits.
4. Add one.   *(note that 1~4 are **exactly equivalent** to your 4-step operations)*
5. Give the result to your computer.

Then our computer would get a binary representation `11111001` (it's `249` in decimal), and it would display it with `-7` on your screen.

In this scenario, you could fairly say that, in an 8-bit computer using TCR,  `-7` is the **alternative** representation of the two's complement number `249`. Although this saying is not much canonical, it helps someone who just learned the notion of TCR for the first time.

In terms of the notion of TCR, please refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), [University Lecture Notes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Etomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html) or [CS books](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7812230-computer-systems) for more precise details, instead of many so-called "online crash courses".